# xcode tab controller connections

Tags: xcode

I have a complete newbie in xcode trying to figure out a Hello world application.
When I use a single view application project, I get apart from appdelegate files..also viewcontroller files (.h and .m). When I put a button and try to connect to the code (ctrl drag); in viewcontroller.h file  it all works fine and generates code automatically.

I tried to start another project with a "Empty application template". Added a story board for designing. The files that now I see in the explorer are only appdelegate.h and .m files (& storyboard file) but no view controller files.

I then drop a tab bar controller into the storyboard.

Question: If I now drag drop a button into the first view controller (of the tab bar)..where can i generate code for this? doesnt the drag drop (ctrl drag) into code work anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a class that is a subclass of UIViewControllers and then assign it to the first view controller (or whichever one you want) inside the designer. This means that after doing so, your view is now part of the class which you just created.

What would be good practise is to create a new project using the TabBar template and then reverse engineer it to know how the template was build.